# How do I run @Before annotations in parallel?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, testng

I have several test classes each of them with `@BeforeClass`.
I have added the option to run in parallel in my xml, but the BeforeClass methods seem to run sequentially.

How do I configure them in a way that they all run at the same time?

```
<suite name = "TestAllPersonTypes">

    <test name = "TestEmployer" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
        <classes>
            <class name = "com.mobile.tests.empr.ValidateEmployerBusinessA"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name = "TestEmployee" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
        <classes>
            <class name = "com.mobile.tests.empe.ValidateEmployeeBusinessA"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name = "TestAgent" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
        <classes>
            <class name = "com.mobile.tests.agnt.ValidateAgentBusinessA"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you are doing now so we can see? Your xml and an example of your classes.

Comment: I added my xml. I can add my tests tomorrow, because I have to change the information of my project and they are many classes. But they are basically simple classes with several tests and a beforeclass method in each class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem there is that you are specifying the parallelism for each test.
You are basically telling each test to run its methods in parallel.

What you need to do is to tell your entire suite to run your tests in parallel. This way, every method of every class (not only the @Before annotations) will run in parallel.

You do this by removing the parallelization from your tests and adding to the suite:

```
<test name = "TestEmployer">
    <classes>
        <class name = "com.mobile.tests.empr.ValidateEmployerBusinessA"/>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name = "TestEmployee">
    <classes>
        <class name = "com.mobile.tests.empe.ValidateEmployeeBusinessA"/>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name = "TestAgent">
    <classes>
        <class name = "com.mobile.tests.agnt.ValidateAgentBusinessA"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

You can have more information of this in the [testNG docs for parallelism.](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running)

Comment: Can you show me how the entire xml would look like? Like how I have it printed above.

Comment: There. Is that what you need?